# How do I get the source code from a Google Code game project?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the Hedgewars source code.  When I went to the downloads tab, it doesn't specify which is the actual game.  I tried downloading it using the SVN Checkout on Tortoise, but it seems like it doesn't work on the browse section of Source.

(Hg>project_files>Android_build>SDL-android-project)

I then proceeded to the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/wiki/HedgeroidGuide) but I got stuck at step two because I don't know anything about Mercurial.
Some other things I don't know from the wiki is "FreePascal" "Android NDK" and "Tar" files.  They are new to me so I am really confused.

So my question is, how can I download the source code from Hedge Wars for Android without having to browse the source code inside the source tab?

Comment: I also want this question answered in a general response because I would like to download and learn more from other source codes in the future

Comment: Mercurial is an alternative to SVN, you will probably need to install someting like TortoiseHg (HG is the element mercurial) to download from the repositories. As for FreePascal it's a programming language. And the Android NDK is something used to write native code for android device. It's probably used by the Hedgewars guys.

Comment: Afaik hedgewars is a mix of freepascal with some C++. (SDL?) probably need the NDK for assembler+linking (and maybe the C++ compiler)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not an issue specific to game development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Code supports several version control systems (SVN, Mercurial and git as of this writing). [Hedgewars](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/) appears to be using Mercurial, as you can see from the [Source -> Checkout tab on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/source/checkout). To get the code, you must clone the repository as described on that page, using either the command line [Mercurial tools](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or a GUI wrapper like [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/).

In general, to get the code from any Google Code project, you navigate to that project's Source -> Checkout page and follow the instructions. Some projects will also create .zip or tarballs of the their code and host them on the Downloads tab, but [Hedgewars does not appear to do this](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/downloads/list) currently, so you'll have to get the code the aforementioned way.

Some projects also provide a wiki page, [like the one you linked](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/wiki/HedgeroidGuide), that further explain any dependencies or special steps you'd need to take to acquire and build the code. Not all projects do this, however.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error from the cloning. hg clone https://hedgewars.googlecode.com/hg/ hedgewars - I copied from https to hegewars and inserted it into the Source, and I put my destination to an empty folder on the desktop.  But an error comes up.

Comment: "an error" isn't helpful -- you should specify which error.

Comment: Sorry, the program was unresponsive so i was forced to close it so i couldn't get the error message, I'm cloning it right now.

Answer (score 2):

To checkout the source code you need to use [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) as there is no official svn repository. Simply `hg clone https://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/` as stated on [the google code](http://code.google.com/p/hedgewars/source/checkout) page.

If you are not comfortable with the command line you can try using one of the [Mercurial user interfaces](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools#Graphical_user_interfaces).

---

If you don't want to use mercurial the [download section on the hedgewars website](http://www.hedgewars.org/download.html) has a direct link to a compressed archive of the source code.